# Is "We were going to meet tomorrow" correct?

Tags: verbs, sequence-of-tenses

If we made plans yesterday to meet tonight, but we didn't meet, I think it's correct to say

> Weren't we going to meet tonight?

and

> We were going to meet tonight.

But if we made plans yesterday to meet tomorrow, is it correct to say

> Weren't we going to meet tomorrow?

or

> We were going to meet tomorrow

?

Comment: I agree this is a better question for ELL. But yes, that’s correct. “We were going to meet tomorrow” means that (in the past) you made plans to meet, and your plans were for the day after *today* (when you are speaking). If you want to refer to the day after the day that you made the plans, you would say *we were going to meet **the next day***.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both of these alternatives are good ways to say that yesterday you made plans for two days from then, which today we call "tomorrow."